# removal of active class from nav tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well, i tried to create a layout like instagram and faced the following problem. I hope i'll get help from experts in this regard. And i tried various ways to remove the active class after clicking on the nav tab , but everytime there arose a problem. let me know how can i remove the active class from this piece of javascript as attached below.

```
<div class="menu">
  <p data-target="#initial" class="active">Initial</p>
  <p data-target="#product">Product</p>
  <p data-target="#contact">Contact</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div data-content id="initial" class="active">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="product">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="contact">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
body{
  padding: 5%;
}
.menu{
  display:flex;
}
.menu p{
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content{
  margin-top:2rem;
}
[data-content]{
  display:none;
}
.active[data-content]{
  display:block;
}
.menu .active{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#FFF;
  background: #000;
  padding:  5px 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.menu p{
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.cards{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  min-width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.card{
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #fff;
}
```

```
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');
const content = document.querySelectorAll('[data-content]');

targets.forEach(target => {
  target.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   
    content.forEach(c => {
      c.classList.remove('active')
      
    })
    
    const t = document.querySelector(target.dataset.target)
    t.classList.add('active');
      target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code is almost working, but there are typos in `contents` instead `content`. That typo makes javascript returns an error and the code below doesn't be executed. And you can remove the active class from that tab by `targets.forEach(...`

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-content]');

targets.forEach(target => {
  target.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    
    targets.forEach(t => {
      t.classList.remove('active')
    })
    contents.forEach(c => {
      c.classList.remove('active')
    })
    
    const t = document.querySelector(target.dataset.target)
    t.classList.add('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
body{
  padding: 5%;
}
.menu{
  display:flex;
}
.menu p{
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content{
  margin-top:2rem;
}
[data-content]{
  display:none;
}
.active[data-content]{
  display:block;
}
.menu .active{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#FFF;
  background: #000;
  padding:  5px 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.menu p{
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.cards{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  min-width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.card{
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p data-target="#initial" class="active">Initial</p>
  <p data-target="#product">Product</p>
  <p data-target="#contact">Contact</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div data-content id="initial" class="active">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="product">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="contact">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classList.remove()

Example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("targetid");
  element.classList.remove("active");
```

[More documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: didn't work for me. please try to write on my code